# Can I format NULL values in string.Format?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, string.format

I was wondering if there's a syntax for formatting NULL values in string.Format, such as what Excel uses

For example, using Excel I could specify a format value of `{0:#,000.00;-#,000.00,NULL}`, which means display the numeric value as number format if positive, number format in parenthesis if negative, or NULL if the value is null

```
string.Format("${0:#,000.00;(#,000.00);NULL}", someNumericValue);
```

**Edit**

I'm looking for formatting `NULL`/`Nothing` values for all data types, not just numeric ones.

My example is actually incorrect because I mistakenly thought Excel used the 3rd parameter if the value was NULL, but it's actually used when the value is 0. I'm leaving it in there because it's the closest thing I can think of to what I was hoping to do.

I am hoping to avoid the null coalescing operator because I am writing log records, and the data is not usually a string

It would be much easier to write something like

```
Log(string.Format("Value1 changes from {0:NULL} to {1:NULL}", 
    new object[] { oldObject.SomeValue, newObject.SomeValue }));
```

than to write

```
var old = (oldObject.SomeValue == null ? "null" : oldObject.SomeValue.ToString());
var new = (newObject.SomeValue == null ? "null" : newObject.SomeValue.ToString());

Log(string.Format("Value1 changes from {0} to {1}", 
    new object[] { old, new }));
```

Comment: `null` (`Nothing` in Visual Basic) or `0` (zero)?

Comment: @dtb I'm looking for formatting `null` / `Nothing`

Comment: @JimMischel Sorry, I was thinking Excel formatted NULL values with the 3rd parameter. It's actually zeros. I'll update my question, but I'm leaving the Excel example in there since it's the closest thing I can think of to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can define a [custom formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0asazeez%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that returns `"NULL"` if the value is `null` and otherwise the default formatted string, e.g.:

```
foreach (var value in new[] { 123456.78m, -123456.78m, 0m, (decimal?)null })
{
    string result = string.Format(
        new NullFormat(), "${0:#,000.00;(#,000.00);ZERO}", value);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

*Output:*

```
$123.456,78
$(123.456,78)
$ZERO
$NULL
```

*Custom Formatter:*

```
public class NullFormat : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type service)
    {
        if (service == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        if (arg == null)
        {
            return "NULL";
        }
        IFormattable formattable = arg as IFormattable;
        if (formattable != null)
        {
            return formattable.ToString(format, provider);
        }
        return arg.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works exactly how I was hoping it would work! You've just made my life a whole lot easier :)

Comment: This is not working for me.  I am writting a JsonValueFormatter and the null value is never entering the Format method.  If I do `string.Format(formatter, "Test: {0}, {1}, {2}", true, 10, null, "Hello")` it returns `Test: true, 10, , "Hello"`.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think there's anything in `String.Format` that will let you specify a particular format for `null` strings. A workaround is to use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), like this:

```
const string DefaultValue = "(null)";

string s = null;
string formatted = String.Format("{0}", s ?? DefaultValue);
```

Comment: See my updated question. I was hoping to avoid using `??` because the data is not usually a string

Comment: @Rachel: See my updated response. There's no reason you need to restrict the null-coalescing operator to strings.

Comment: Yes, but I want the default value to be `"NULL"` even if the data type is a number or a date. I cannot use `someNumber ?? "NULL"` because the string `"NULL"` is not the same data type as `someNumber`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
string test;
```

test ?? "NULL"

Comment: See my updated question. I was hoping to avoid using `??` because the data is not usually a string

Answer (score 1):

It looks like String.Format for .NET acts the same way as Excel, i.e., you can use `;` separator for positive, negative, and 0 values, but not NULL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator.

You will probably just have to handle the null value manually:

```
if (myval == null)
    // handle
else
    return String.Format(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension method:

```
 public static string ToDataString(this string prm)
   {
       if (prm == null)
       {
           return "NULL";
       }
       else
       {
           return "'" + prm.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
       }
   }
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
string Field1="Val";
string Field2=null;

string s = string.Format("Set Value:{0}, NullValue={1}",Field1.ToDataString(), Field2.ToDataString());
```