# best way of formatting string objects

Tags: c#, string

I want to create a string object like this

```
string data = "85-null-null-null-null-price-down-1-20";   // null if zero
```

I have a method like this.

```
 public static DataSet LoadProducts(int CategoryId, string Size, 
                                   string Colour, Decimal LowerPrice, 
                                   Decimal HigherPrice, string SortExpression, 
                                   int PageNumber, int PageSize, 
                                   Boolean OnlyClearance)
 {
      /// Code goes here 
      /// i am goona pass that string to one more method here

      var result = ProductDataSource.Load(stringtoPass) // which accepts only the above format

 }
```

I know I can use a `StringBuilder`, but using that would require too many lines of code. I am looking here for a minimalistic solution here.

Comment: You say you want a string, and then you show a method with return type of DataSet, is this a typo?

Comment: no.. i am goona work on that string inside the method.

Comment: already on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689040/can-i-format-null-values-in-string-format

Comment: why -1 for the question. whats wrong in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}-{8}",
                     CategoryId,
                     Size ?? "null", 
                     Colour ?? "null",
                     LowerPrice != 0 ? LowerPrice.ToString() : "null",
                     HigherPrice != 0 ? HigherPrice.ToString() : "null",
                     SortExpression ?? "null",
                     PageNumber != 0 ? PageNumber.ToString() : "null",
                     PageSize != 0 ? PageSize.ToString() : "null", 
                     OnlyClearance);
```

For convenience, you could create extension methods:

```
public static string NullStringIfZero(this int value)
{
    return value != 0 ? value.ToString() : "null";
}

public static string NullStringIfZero(this decimal value)
{
    return value != 0 ? value.ToString() : "null";
}
```

And use them as follows:

```
return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}-{8}",
                     CategoryId,
                     Size ?? "null", 
                     Colour ?? "null",
                     LowerPrice.NullStringIfZero(),
                     HigherPrice.NullStringIfZero(),
                     SortExpression ?? "null",
                     PageNumber.NullStringIfZero(),
                     PageSize.NullStringIfZero(),
                     OnlyClearance);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string foo = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}-{8}",
                           CategoryId,
                           Size ?? "null" ... );
```

Answer (score 2):

please override the ToString method of the object with the format you prefer and call the Object.tostring() method

Example on request after comment:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Field1 {get; private set;}
  public string Field2 {get; private set;}

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format("Field1 = {0} , Field2 = {1}", Field1, Field2);
   }
}
```

Now advantage of doing this way are:

1. In your method you can use only 1 parameter of type Foo
2. When your debugging and stop on a break point as you Add object of foo to watch you will see the string representation
3. If you decide to print all you have to do is Console.WriteLine(foo)

Comment: Why -2 I am saying the same thing as others only difference is I am not giving complete code

Comment: please show your complete code using ToString() i would love to see how things done differently...