# WPF DateTime Formatting

Tags: wpf, datetime, formatting

I need to format the Date, so I used the below:

```
        <xcdg:Column Title="Registratiedatum" FieldName="RegistratieDatum" Width="1*">
        <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss }', TargetNullValue={x:Static System:String.Empty}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
        </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        </xcdg:Column>
```

However, some of the Date is Null, so I would like those fields to remain empty, but I guess due to the formatting it appears like this:

01/01/0001 00:00:00

Any idea how to restrict the format only for "not null" values? Sorry, if it might be too basic question, but I am still at the beginning stage of learning.

Comment: are they really `null`? DateTime is `struct` and initial value is exactly `01/01/0001 00:00:00`.

Comment: Since DateTime is a struct it cannot be null. Besides that, you may use a Binding Converter instead of StringFormat.

Comment: In the database it shows as following:
column: [DAT_EERSTE_VERWERKING](datetime,null)
and some values are NULL.

@Clemens: I also was thinking of using a Converter(never used it so far), but was hoping there might be an easier solution.

Anyway, thanks for your fast reply, guys!

Comment: Than probably your property is generated as `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`. Anyway, a converter should do the job here.

Comment: You can use a custom formatter that returns null for empty values
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689040/can-i-format-null-values-in-string-format

Comment: try to set  to empty `TargetNullValue` like this `TargetNullValue=''`.

Comment: @StepUp: unfortunately it didn't work this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Struct` being a `value type`, it can never be `null`.

However, there are several ways you can fix your issue:

1. the cleanest and most logical, in my opinion, is to change your DateTime into a `Nullable<Datetime>`

   ```
   private DateTime? myDate;
   public DateTime? MyDate
   {
        get
        {
           return this.myDate;
        }
        set
        {
           this.myDate = value;
        }
   }
   ```
2. if this is not an option, a converter will do the trick:

   .xaml code:

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <local:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
   </UserControl.Resources>         

   <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDate, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" />
   ```

   .cs code

   ```
   public class DateConverter: IValueConverter
   {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
        if (value != null)
        {
           DateTime myDate = (DateTime)value;
           if (myDate != DateTime.MinValue)
           {
              return myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
           }
        }

        return String.Empty;
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
   }
   ```
3. finally, a DataTrigger directly in the Xaml code allows you to hide/collapse the control when the date is null. The key, as in the converter is to check when the date is equal to `DateTime.MinValue`.

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplicationTest.MyUserControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss }'}" >
           <TextBlock.Style>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyDate}" Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.MinValue}">
                          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                       </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                 </Style>
              </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am impressed by the various options you have provided. In my case, since the TextBox is actually a field within xcdg Datagrid, the option 2 was the chosen one - works just as expected.